# String Output shows null but why?

Tags: c, string

My Program is to Check if a String is a Palindrome.
But it show  while is print the string. I can't find the error..

I am using Dev-Cpp

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

main()
{
 char string[25], rev_string[25]={'\0'};
 int i, length, flag=0;

 printf("Enter a string : ");
 gets(string);

 length=strlen(string);

 for(i=length; i>=0;i--)
  {
    rev_string[length-i-1]=string[i];
    flag=0;
    printf("%s",rev_string[length-i]);
  }

 for(flag=1,i=0; i<length;i++)
  {
    if(rev_string[i]!=string[i])    
    {
        flag=0;
    }   
  }
 if (flag == 1)
   printf ("%s is a palindrome \n", string);
 else
   printf("%s is not a palindrome \n", string);

 printf("%d",length);

}
```

Comment: Use `for(i=length-1 ; i>=0;i--)`.

Comment: Fyi, a pair of pointers makes short work of checking a string for the palindrome property. No intermediate buffer should be needed. [**Example**](http://pastebin.com/rkSq2Q0f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
for(i=length; i>=0;i--)
  {
    rev_string[length-i-1]=string[i]; //For first iteration string[i] is '\0' here,also here you are accessing rev_string[-1]
    flag=0;
    printf("%s",rev_string[length-i]);  //here undefined behavior expected as format specifier in printf does not match with argument. 
  }
```

With

```
 for(i=length-1; i>0;i--)
  {
    rev_string[length-i-1]=string[i];
    flag=0;

  }
  rev_string[length] = '\0';
  printf("%s",rev_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't anything particularly wrong with the logic in your program. But there were a few things I noticed could be improved on.

First: Defining `main` without saying it's return type will automagically make it default to integer. No where in your program do you `return 0;`

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The other large detail is this line in particular `printf("%s",rev_string[length-i]);`. You said "print this string" with %s but then you say `rev_string[length-i]`, which is only a single character! So you will need to change the `%s` to a `%c` if you want to print each character. If you keep it as %s, it might be a good idea to print it outside of a loop, and only use `rev_string` without the index. I chose to do the latter in my example.

Another small detail, though not important, was in your first for loop you're saying `flag=0` a lot of times! If you set it once, I'm sure the computer would be nice enough to remember the first time you tell it. Besides, it's not important that `flag` has a value yet. In your second while loop, it gets the value 1 100% of the time. That's where it's most important too. So we can remove it from the for loop. This is unnecessary:

```
for(i=length; i>=0;i--) {
    flag=0;
}
```

I changed the for loop that reverses the string. It does the same thing you specified but in reverse. Keep yours if you'd like, but I always like to count starting with 0 when I can.

Here's the reformatted version with my suggestions:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[25];
    char rev_string[25];

    // we don't need flag to have a value until the second for loop
    int i, length, flag;

    printf("Enter a string : ");
    // scanf is nice for user input
    scanf("%s", string);

    length=strlen(string);

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {   
        rev_string[i] = string[length-i-1];
    }
    // This tells where the string ends
    rev_string[length] = '\0';

    printf("Reversed string: %s\n", rev_string);

    // flag is 1 here, until rev_string[i]!=string[i]
    for(flag=1,i=0; i<length;i++)
    {
        if(rev_string[i]!=string[i])    
        {
            flag=0;
        }   
    }
    if (flag == 1)
        printf ("%s is a palindrome \n", string);
    else
        printf("%s is not a palindrome \n", string);

    printf("Length: %d\n",length);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In first `for` loop you have placed this line,

```
printf("%s",rev_string[length-i]);
```

`%s` is for printing the string not a single character. You can just remove this line or place like this,

```
printf("%s\n",rev_string);
```

Or use %c ,

```
printf("%c",rev_string[length-i]);
```

And use `fgets`  instead of `gets`.

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to reverse the string, you can simply have one index `i` that starts at the beginning of the string, and another `j` that starts at the end of the string. Check that `string[i] == string[j]` while incrementing `i` and decrementing `j`, until `i` and `j` meet in the middle.

```
int isPalindrome( char *string )
{
    int length = strlen( string );

    for ( int i = 0, j = length-1; i < j; i++, j-- )
        if ( string[i] != string[j] )
            return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main( void )
{
    if ( isPalindrome( "hello" ) )
        printf( "what the ???\n" );
    else
        printf( "nope\n" );

    if ( isPalindrome( "racecar" ) )
        printf( "yup\n" );
    else
        printf( "hey ?!?!\n" );
}
```